# How to find max element index for a specific value in list composed of class objects?

Tags: python, list, class, max

I want to find a maximum elements index in a nested list for each row.

I got this error:

```
maxe = array[i].index(max(e_object.x for e_object in array[i]))
ValueError: 5 is not in list
```

```
class e_object():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

array = []
array.append( [])
array[0].append(e_object(0))
array[0].append(e_object(2))
array[0].append(e_object(-3))
array[0].append(e_object(5))

array.append( [])
array[1].append(e_object(0))
array[1].append(e_object(2))
array[1].append(e_object(8))
array[1].append(e_object(5))

max_array = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    maxe = array[i].index(max(e_object.x for e_object in array[i]))
    max_array.append(maxe)

print(max_array)
```

How can I get this result?

```
[3,2]
```

Comment: list and array mean different things in Python. What you have is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `list` comprehension to convert the nested `list` into one of `x` values, and then use `np.argmax`:

```
import numpy as np

np.argmax([[element.x for element in row] for row in array], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([3, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: without any loop, so good. how can represent the result like [3,2] ?

Comment: Just call `.tolist()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is line

```
maxe = array[i].index(max(e_object.x for e_object in array[i]))
```

You are asking the index of `object.x`, but the list actually contains `object`. Change the `max` function to look inside the objects `x` attribute

```
maxe = array[i].index(max(array[i], key=lambda o: o.x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because your `max` effectively operates on a list of integers `[0, 2, -3, 5]`, while `index` searches in a list of `e_object`s. There are any number of ways of fixing this issue.

The simplest is probably to just have `max` return the index:

```
max_array = [max(range(len(a)), key=lambda x: a[x].x) for a in array]
```

This is very similar to using `numpy`'s `argmax`, but without the heavy import and intermediate memory allocations. Notice that this version does not require two passes over each list since you don't call `index` on the result of `max`.

A more long term solution would be to add the appropriate comparison methods, like `__eq__` and `__gt__`/`__lt__` to the `e_object` class.

Comment: it says : TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'e_object' and 'e_object'